# lenovo x1 carbon windows 8 frequent WiFi disconnect issue

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, thinkpad

**I'm having frequent WiFi disconnects on my `Lenovo X1 Carbon Touch` laptop**.

I got this laptop 2 months back and it has been happening ever since about 3-5 times a day and 10 times a week on average. I've Frontier Fios internet. Power connected or not does not matter.

Once I get disconnected, I try below to connect again in that order:

- turn Airplane mode on and off,
- troubleshoot network problems windows troubleshooter),
- restart the laptop

I'd find that the WiFi adapter would get disabled and sometimes windows troubleshooting would help but more than often I'd end up restarting the laptop.

A week back, I upgraded my wifi network adapter drivers (now `Intel, version 15.5.6.48, 10/3/2012`). I still get disconnected frequently but turning Airplane mode on and off gets me connected again. So the driver update did help.

Windows 8 is updated.

None of the other devices (nexus, iphone phones, nexus7, ipad tablets) would have wifi issues when my laptop would get disconnected.

config:

```
Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6205 (WiFi network adapter)
Microsoft Windows 8 Pro Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]
x64-based PC
LENOVO
System Model: 3443CTO
X1 Carbon Touch
```

I recently noticed this log message When I got disconnected in event viewer:

> Your computer was not assigned an address from the network (by the
>   DHCP Server) for the Network Card with network address 0x[XXXXXXXXXXXX].
>   The following error occurred: 0x79. Your computer will continue to try
>   and obtain an address on its own from the network address (DHCP)
>   server.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue with some of the latest intel wifi cards. And even if you dont tell, the lenovo x1 carbon, comes with the same wifi card as the sony vaio pro 13 ( the one i just returned )...

While looking from an alternative to the just returned laptop, and lenovo was in my shoping list, until i found this:

http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/X-Series-ThinkPad-Laptops/Massive-wifi-issues-with-X1-Carbon-Touch/td-p/1217938

Not as many as the related sony vaio pages here..
http://community.sony.com/t5/VAIO-Hardware-Networking/New-Sony-Vaio-Pro-Wifi-Issue/td-p/143557/page/177 ( Yes. that is 177 pages of people with the same issue )

But as i said, it seems an intel problem: There are more resources about what i believe is the same problem this more generic, and refers to the 6230/6235 adapter, but in the comments you can read people with the same issue on the 7260 AC adapters too ( can not post the link, search for "Intel's Wi-Fi adapters connectivity issues continue"

And of course you can just google for "7260 wifi issues", or add "lenovo X1 carbon" to the query.

good luck

Comment: I have not been having this issue for quite some time. I believe the intel wifi card driver update did fix / mitigate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues with the intel 7260 card in my Lenovo Yoga 2 pro. I followed the advice in the forum and replaced the card:

Search for your laptop's manual and and see what cards are compatible.

Here are some forum postings and official lenovo instructions on replacing the wifi card in a carbon x1:
https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/X-Series-ThinkPad-Laptops/Wifi-card-upgrade-options-for-X1-Carbon-NGFF-SFF-HMC-WP2/td-p/1248231

http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?DocID=PD030270

Find the correct page for your model and get a better card. It took me longer to research which was the correct card than it did for me to replace the card. You'll thank yourself when you replace it! I no longer have any wifi issues.

**Make sure you get the correct card for your model!**